# jasmine test cases for window location

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to write jasmine test cases for window.location but facing the error

```
Problem accessing url Reason: Not Found
```

in Html

`<button ng-click="takeAction()" >`

in  controller i check for the security 

      `$scope.takeAction=function()
      {
          if(user=="X")
          {
            downloadcsv(url);
          }else{
         downloadcsv(anotherurl);
      };
      function downloadcsv(u){
             $window.location(u);
      }`

Comment: I don't see url or anotherurl being declared anywhere. Are these global variables?

Comment: I'm just passing the url to the method , th above code works fine but while writing hasmine i'm facing issues

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant jasmine code?